# "E11000 duplicate key error collection" for empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema where one of the properties is the following:

```
 auctionId: {
    type: [Number],
    unique: true,
    sparse: true,
  },
```

MongoDB gives me the following error whenever several documents have the property as an empty array:

```
Cluster0.tokens index: auctionId_1 dup key: { auctionId: undefined }
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter for the index using [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial).

```
SchemaName.index({ auctionId: 1 }, {
  unique: true,
  partialFilterExpression: {
    'auctionId.0': { $exists: true }
  }
});
```